# Trying to solve an equation on a restricted domain

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve

```
((1 - x)/(x*Z))^x* A^x*B^(1 - x) == M
```

where x is constrained to the interval [0,1] and all other values (A,B,M and Z) are positive real constants. I can find numerical solutions using NSolve, but am wondering if an analytical solutions might be possible on the bounded domain [0,1]?

Comment: is `xZ` one variable?

Comment: It's x*Z. Sorry, can't figure out how to display it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you would probably want to use is the following:

```
Assuming[{{A, B, Z, M} ∈ PositiveReals}, 
 Simplify[Solve[((1 - x)/(x Z))^x* A^x*B^(1 - x) == M && x > 0 && 
    x < 1, x]]]
```

I have not been able to find an analytical solution to this though. You can try leaving it running all day if you want. But I'd safely say there isn't one.